# Error with rvest - NAs introduced by coercion (xpath & css)

Tags: css, xpath, web-scraping, rvest

I'm attempting to scrape a website and collect the daily prices for various articles of clothing over an extended period.  I've followed the tutorial on RStudio's blog but I am unable to replicate the idea on the test set despite using SelectorGadget.  I've tried the follow code still receive NAs:

```
url<- "https://www.zara.com/us/en/authentic-jeans-p00840407.html?v1=9035594&v2=1204074"

    jeans <- url %>%
      read_html() %>%
      html_nodes(".description , .product-price span") %>%
      html_text() %>%
      as.numeric()
```

I've also attempting to use the xpath format and still no luck:

```
jeans <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "product-price", " " ))]') %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.numeric()
```

I'd greatly appreciate any insight you might share - and would **really** appreciate it if you passed along any resources that details how to build a database over time from pulled data / or how to batch rvest webscrape requests!

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like the page uses javascript to update content so you need a method that allows for rendering on the page. You also need to scroll to the bottom of the page to generate content. With respect to your css selectors: your current class selector doesn't exist. The actual one is `_product-price`. You can in fact use .price alone to match in the webpage itself.

Comment: can you provide the link to the blog?

Comment: https://blog.rstudio.com/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/